Best way to report a scam MLM "job" appearing as a job ad? The "company" has been targeting marginalized and disabled people
The ad shown below is a scam.
It's just a multi-level marketing (MLM) scheme wherein, after sitting through a two-hour presentation (which is presented as an "interview"), the mark is asked to pay 2 to 3 thousand dollars in the usual MLM fashion.
Even worse, they continually go after folks who are home bound, disabled and home bound, or under psychiatric care. Some friends had a family member (who suffers severe anxiety, is home bound, and is under psychiatric care) unfortunately apply for the "job" which ended up being a medical nightmare, due to hours of pressure from idiots trying to take their money. (The family in question is now going after the scammers legally, thank God, but it's hard with scam operations like this.)
Aside from anything else, the supposed company is not located in "Newport News" - it is arbitrary address they typed in to the ad generator to sound important and government-related.
The same team of scammers runs a similar ad for "AI training".



The fact the ad is powered by Indeed make me suspect that [so] can do little about it, and that it's Indeed that need to better vet the content that they send out as advertisements to sites like [so].

Apparently you've already reported the ad using the built-in UI for that. Any reason you think you should have done something different?

I'm not sure what you've described here is an MLM. It sounds like a scam, don't get me wrong, but not every scam with a motivational presentation is an MLM. MLMs push their victims to recruit down-line people to multiply their earnings.

If I switch on my VPN for an American IP (as Jobs isn't available outside USA), it looks like the company in question posted 15 jobs all of similar description 13 days ago. That, if nothing else, is normally a red flag for me. 15 cookie cutter roles in a software industry, randomly placed around the world (one says the position is in Athens), normally suggests foul play.

This is probably something to post on MSE as it would be a more general problem with how ads are being chosen?

While Indeed should do something about it Stack Exchange is displaying the ads, and jobs, from Indeed. So it is there none to cross, if they want to partner with Indeed for the new Jobs functionality, and impact visitors to their website. Jobs was never a quality service, even when they had quality control over the content, now with indeed which most definitely advertises fake jobs it’s even worse. Said this in the Indeed announcement, Indeed isn’t the same company it was, and it doesn’t have very many real jobs on it.

Hi @GeneralGrievance - sorry if my post wasn't clear. A family friend (the young adult) went through the process of applying. As I explain in the post, it is indeed an MLM, a pyramid scheme.  (I do not yet know if it is a "titularly legal," ie correctly established as a corp etc in a relavant state where you can get away with it, or, just "some casual, unincorporated scammers")  I'm completely familiar with MLM scams (and indeed legit MLM!) as I work in precisely fraud and security. (As I mention, fortunately the familt is in the process of going after them, cross fingers.)

@SecurityHound ? (Someone from SO would ping Indeed saying "This ad is a well known scam so we won't be running it, Fyi we took it out of the rotation". It's utterly commonplace that a media outlet will tell an advertiser "oh we don't like ad X [because it's vulgar, shady, poorly-made, the audio ducks are broken, it might cross some advertising guideline, my cousin owns a competitor of yours, my wife says she doesn't like the color of the logo, or, no reason given whatsoever] so we clicked it out of rotation, cheers.")

@Fattie Oh, no problem. It was a minor point to the post, but something I care about as I was nearly involved with one in the past. Even this "legit" one asked me to do unethical things, so I left while I could still get my money back.

Are you sure you're identifying the right company? I did some googling and I can see lots of people complaining about them for various reasons (no transparency, poor pay, poor communication and unclear expectations), but zero people suggesting that they're MLM or describing anything like what you're talking about.

@JeremyBanks fair question, but since pyramid schemes have existed for a long time now and are heavily under fire even through Netflix documentaries... I would make a big assumption they have gotten better at hiding it.

@JeremyBanks - Yes.

I have done work for DataAnnotation. There was no interview or presentation (the application was an online test with multiple-choice or written questions), I was never asked to pay them money, and they have paid me on time for my work with no issues. If this advert is a scam, it's posted by some scammers pretending to be DataAnnotation. Where does it take you when you click on it?

@Gimby “better at hiding it” what does that actually mean in this context? There are people on a half dozen websites they don’t control complaining about every aspect of their company, yet somehow they’re specifically managing to suppress discussion of this particular part of their on-boarding process? That doesn’t make sense. It’s possible that some representative of theirs happened to take advantage of their position to attempt a scam, but it seems hard to believe that this is their pattern of behaviour.

@ThomA To be clear, the work that DataAnnotation offer is fully online, but when posting ads to job sites like Indeed they label them with (as far as I know) random places, probably so that their ads will show up on more searches. They aren't looking for people specifically in those places. It's an annoying SEO-ish practice, there is nothing more to it than that. FWIW, I can think of a lot more important-sounding and government-related places than Newport News, VA, which apparently is a real town.

Thank you for raising this concern, we are looking into it. I see that in this case this was a job ad on SO and that you reported the ad (which is the correct course of action), but I also want to note that if potentially scammy job postings are ever found on Stack Overflow Jobs, those can also be reported via the process outlined in this help center article.

"Problems...can be reported directly on Indeed by hitting “apply”...". This is extremely weird, and not at all intuitive.
